# Anagram- Minimum number of char deletion required-'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, anagram

**The below code doesnot work. Why the map function is returning type error?
I have tried a many times. can someone give a proper reason for the below code?**

```
n=26
string_array_1=[0]*n
string_array_2=[0]*n 
string_1='ababc'
string_2='abab'
for char in string_1:
    char_index=list(map[char])
    string_array_1[char_index]=string_array_1[char_index]+1
for char in string_2:
    char_index=string_2.index(char)
    string_array_2[char_index]=string_array_2[char_index]+1   
result=0
for i in range(26):
    abs_diff=abs(string_array_1[i]-string_array_2[i])
    result=result + abs_diff
print(result)
```

Comment: considering all word are small , to get the index you need make the character in range 0-26. so use `ord` function to get the ascii value of the character and subsctract it with `ord('a')` to make it in range 0-25

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this part: `list(map[char])`. [`map(function, iterable, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is a Python built-in (function) that receives a function and applies it to an iterable. The real question is related to what do you expect to receive in `char_index = list(map[char])`.